# Problema de listas de listas en C++

Tags: c++, archivo, estructuras-de-datos, binario

Hola muy buenas tengo un problema con un código llevo horas intentando buscar la lógica o el error pero no lo puedo encontrar, *el error trata de que no me muestra la segunda o mas listas* el problema es una listas de listas donde debo escribir el nombre de la materia(asignatura) y unos complementos de la sub lista e introducirlo dentro de un archivo binario lo probé sin archivo binario y funciono pero a la hora de ingresarlo al archivo binario solo muestra el primero y no el resto de lista

**pd:** Me podrían decir como ir escribiendo código en un archivo binario una vez cerrado, es decir poder escribir "hola" cerrar el archivo abrirlo y escribir "Mundo" y cuando lo quiero abrir diga "hola mundo" y no "mundo".

**pd2:** Pueden probar comentando todo lo que sea de archivos binarios y ejecutar función mostrar_lista

Muchas gracias.

El código es:

```
/*  Estructura ocupada  */
struct Sub_Lista{
    string nivel;
    int sct;
    string tel;
    string naturaleza;
    Sub_Lista *prox;
};

struct Lista{
    string Dato;
    Sub_Lista *Datos;
    Lista *prox;
};
```

---

```
    int main(){
    // Variables 
    Lista *Asignatura = NULL;
    Lista *Fin = NULL;
    Sub_Lista *p = NULL;
    int sct;
    string naturaleza,tel,nivel;
    string lectura;
    ofstream fsalida("prueba.dat", ios::out | ios::binary); // Archivo binario de salida
    // Programa 
    while (lectura != "."){
        p = NULL; // p es un aux
        fflush(stdin);
        cout << "Ingrese el nombre de la asignatura: ";
        getline(cin,lectura);
        if (lectura != "."){
            nivel = " ";
            while (nivel != ".") {
                fflush(stdin);
                cout << "ingrese el nivel: ";
                getline(cin,nivel);
                if (nivel != "."){
                    fflush(stdin);
                    cout << "Ingrese el TEL: ";
                    getline(cin,tel);
                    fflush(stdin);
                    cout << "Ingrese la naturaleza: ";
                    getline(cin,naturaleza);
                    fflush(stdin);
                    cout << "Ingrese su sct: ";
                    cin >> sct;

                    ingresar_sub_lista(p,sct,naturaleza,tel,nivel); // Ingresamos todos los datos y lo guardamos en p
                }
            }
            // Aca puede que este el error 
            insertar(Asignatura,Fin,lectura,p);// Luego P y el nombre de la asignatura lo guardamos en Asignatura
            fsalida.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Asignatura), sizeof(Lista));
        }
    }
    fsalida.close();

    //mostrar_lista(Asignatura); //Con esta función muestra los punteros bien
    Lectura_archivo();

    while (Asignatura){ // Para eliminar los nodos
        while (Asignatura){ // Vaciamos Asignatura->Datos y lo dejamos en null
            eliminar_sub_lista(Asignatura->Datos,sct,naturaleza,tel,nivel);
        }
        // Luego elimanmos la asignatura
        eliminar_lista(Asignatura,Fin,lectura);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

---

```
/* Funciones utilizadas */
void insertar(Lista *&Inicio,Lista *&fin,string asignatura,Sub_Lista *p){
    Lista *nuevo_nodo = new Lista();
    nuevo_nodo->Dato = asignatura;
    nuevo_nodo->Datos = p;
    nuevo_nodo->prox = NULL;

    if (Inicio == NULL){
        Inicio = nuevo_nodo;
    }else{
        fin->prox = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    fin = nuevo_nodo;
}

void ingresar_sub_lista(Sub_Lista *&Inicio,int sct,string naturaleza,string tel,string nivel){
    Sub_Lista *Nodo = new Sub_Lista();
    Nodo->nivel = nivel;
    Nodo->sct = sct;
    Nodo->tel = tel;
    Nodo->naturaleza = naturaleza;
    Nodo->prox = Inicio;
    Inicio = Nodo;
}

void eliminar_lista(Lista *&Inicio,Lista *&fin,string &dato){
    Lista *nuevo_nodo = new Lista();
    dato = Inicio->Dato;
    Lista *aux = Inicio;
    if (Inicio == fin){
        Inicio =  NULL;
        fin = NULL;
    }else{
        Inicio = Inicio->prox;
    }
    delete aux;
}

void eliminar_sub_lista(Sub_Lista *&Inicio,int &sct,string &naturaleza,string &tel,string &nivel){
    Sub_Lista *aux = Inicio;
    sct = aux->sct;
    naturaleza = aux->naturaleza;
    tel = aux->tel;
    nivel = aux->nivel;
    Inicio = aux->prox;
    delete aux;
}

// El error debe estar en esta funcion o en la de escritura 
void Lectura_archivo(){ 
    ifstream fentrada("prueba.dat", ios::in | ios::binary); // Archivo binario de entrada
    Lista *Nodo_lista = NULL;

    while (!fentrada.eof() && fentrada.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Nodo_lista), sizeof(Lista))){ // O puede que este aca 
        fentrada.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Nodo_lista), sizeof(Lista));
        cout << "\t\t\tAsignatura: " << Nodo_lista->Dato << endl;
        while (Nodo_lista->Datos && !fentrada.eof()){
            cout << "Nivel: " << Nodo_lista->Datos->nivel << endl;
            cout << "TEL: " << Nodo_lista->Datos->tel << endl;
            cout << "SCT: " << Nodo_lista->Datos->sct << endl;
            cout << "Naturaleza: " << Nodo_lista->Datos->naturaleza << endl;
            Nodo_lista->Datos = Nodo_lista->Datos->prox;
        }
        fentrada.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Nodo_lista), sizeof(Lista));
    }

}

void mostrar_lista(Lista *Nodo){
    Lista *aux = new Lista();
    aux = Nodo;
    if (Nodo == NULL){
        cout << "Lista vacia" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "\nElementos de la lista\n" << endl;
        while(aux != NULL){
            cout << "Asignatura: " <<aux->Dato << endl;
            mostrar_sub_lista(aux->Datos);
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
        cout << "\nLita recorrida! \n" << endl;
    }
}

void mostrar_sub_lista(Sub_Lista *Nodo){
    Sub_Lista *aux = new Sub_Lista();
    aux = Nodo;
    if (Nodo == NULL){
        cout << "Lista vacia" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Sub lista de la asignatura" << endl;
        while(aux != NULL){
            cout << "Nivel: " << aux->nivel << endl;
                cout << "TEL: " << aux->tel << endl;
                cout << "SCT: " << aux->sct << endl;
                cout << "Naturaleza: " << aux->naturaleza << endl;
                aux = aux->prox;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando se trabaja con archivos binarios se debe recuperar la información del archivo, es decir ya que esta guardando una estructura recupera la lista la agrega a otra estructura junto con el nuevo dato y la guarda, ahora las cosas cambian si no necesita guardar la estructura sino los datos y no tiene problema en que sea en archivo de texto, ahí si se puede guardar valores sin sobre escribir, es decir generar esa lista de información, pero solo con archivos planos. Un saludo

Comment: Considera usar las [list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/list-cpp-stl/) de la Standar Template Library de C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu programa tiene varios problemas que podemos ir enumerando

**fflush**

`fflush` únicamente debe usarse **con *streams* de salida**, nunca con *streams* de entrada. La propia [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) lo deja bien claro:

> In all other cases, the behavior depends on the specific library implementation. In some implementations, flushing a stream open for reading causes its input buffer to be cleared (but this is not portable expected behavior).

Que viene a decir:

> En el resto de casos el comportamiento depende de la implementación específica de la librería. En algunas implementaciones, ejecutar `fflush` en un *stream* abierto en *lectura* provoca el *vaciado** del mismo (pero no es un comportamiento portable)

Vamos, que en tu casa funcionará pero es probable que en otro sistema (o simplemente actualizando el compilador) no haga lo que esperas.

**Mezclar IO de C y de C++**

C++ incorpora sus propios objetos para interactuar con la entrada/salida. No hace falta, por tanto, usar los mecanismos heredados de C... o al menos, si optas por usar estos últimos... **no los mezcles**.

Tu caso funciona porque ambos sistemas están sincronizados... pero tu solución es tan facil de romper como llamar a:

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Al realizar esta llamada (que puede hacerse desde cualquier sitio), verás que los tiempos de ejecución de `cin` y `cout` bajan enormemente... pero también que la mezcla de `stdin` y `cin` da resultados extraños.

**Una lista no es un nodo**

De la misma manera que un escalón no es una escalera. No elegir una arquitectura adecuada suele provocar que el código sea más propenso a errores y más dificil de seguir.

Es un tema que se ha discutido varias veces en StackOverflow, así que te animo a navegar un poco por las preguntas que tratan temas de listas tanto en C como en C++.

**Usa constructores**

En C++ las clases pueden tener constructores. Estas funciones son especiales y se ejecutarán **siempre** que se cree un objeto. El objetivo de estas funciones es garantizar que los objetos que creamos se encuentren desde el principio en un estado *usable*.

```
struct Sub_Lista{
    string nivel;
    int sct;
    string tel;
    string naturaleza;
    Sub_Lista *prox;

    Sub_Lista(std::string const& nivel_,
              int sct_,
              std::string const& tel,
              std::string const& naturaleza_)
      : nivel(nivel_)
      , sct(sct_)
      , tel(tel_)
      , naturaleza(naturaleza_)
      , prox(nullptr)
    { }
};
```

Este constructor permite hacer algo como esto:

```
Sub_Lista * aux = new Sub_Lista("nivel", 12345, "telefono", "naturaleza");
```

**Fugas de memoria**

```
Lista *aux = new Lista();
aux = Nodo;
```

En el código que precede a este párrafo estás creando fugas de memoria. Creas un objeto de tipo `Lista` en la memoria dinámica y guardas su posición de memoria en `aux`... en la siguiente línea haces que `aux` apunte a `Nodo`... por lo que la direción de memoria que tenía antes se pierde irremediablemente y el nuevo objeto se queda en el limbo de los muertos vivientes.

El siguiente código hace lo mismo pero sin generar fugas de memoria:

```
Lista *aux = Nodo;
```

**ojo con las clases**

Hay dos instrucciones especialmente peligrosas en tu código:

```
fsalida.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Asignatura), sizeof(Lista));
fentrada.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Nodo_lista), sizeof(Lista));
```

Para saber qué tienen de peligroso vamos a ver la declaración de la clase `Lista`

```
struct Lista{
    string Dato;
    Sub_Lista *Datos;
    Lista *prox;
};
```

Esta clase tiene un objeto de tipo `std::string` y dos punteros. Vamos a hacer una prueba:

```
std::string cadena;
std::cout << sizeof(cadena) << '\n';
cadena = "Aquí escribo El Quijote ENTERO: En un lugar de la mancha de cuyo nombre ...";

std::cout << sizeof(cadena) << '\n';
```

¿Cómo puede ser que se imprima el mismo valor las dos veces? ¿Y todo el texto que he introducido?

Las clases en C++ pueden tener punteros y `std::string` no es una excepción. Por tanto si tu haces:

```
fsalida.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Asignatura), sizeof(Lista));
```

Estás guardando la dirección de memoria apuntada por dichos punteros en vez de guardar los objetos apuntados.

Es lógico pensar que al leer esos datos es altamente improbable que los objetos se encuentren mágicamente en el mismo sitio...

Así pues al leer obtendrás unas direcciones de memoria que no son válidas en absoluto.

En C te pasa exactamente lo mismo... solo que en tus prácticas no has tenido que serializar estructuras que hagan uso de memoria dinámica... no obstante sería una práctica interesante.

Lo dicho: **no puedes serializar objetos que usen memoria dinámica directamente** tienes que guardar su estado parte por parte:

```
while( Asignatura != nullptr )
{
  fsalida << Asignatura->Dato;

  // Guardar la lista de datos ...

  Asignatura = Asignatura->prox;
}
```

Y algo parecido a la hora de leer:

```
Lista* asignatura = nullptr;
Lista* fin = nullptr;
while( true )
{
  std::string dato;
  fentrada >> dato;
  if( fentrada.eof() )
    break;

  Lista* nodo = new Lista(dato); // Necesita el constructor Lista(std::string const&)
  if( asignaturas == nullptr )
    asignaturas = nodo;
  else
    fin->prox = nodo;
  fin = nodo;

  // Leemos la sublista

}

return asignaturas;
```

Comment: hola me podrías ayudar con unas dudas que quede sobre lo que escribió : 

1) me intereso lo de bajar los tiempos "std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);" que funcion comple? y sobre escribir "using namespace std" entonces no es confiable ?
2) en el contructor de Sub_Lista al poner "nivel(nivel_)" es lo "mismo" que nivel = nivel_ ? y por que al final quedan unas llaves vacias "{ }" 
3) El ultimo codigo que escribio como seria la creacion de la variable "fentrada" seria de la misma forma "ifstream fentrada("prueba.dat", ios::in | ios::binary) " ?
4) Cuando ocupar fflush?

Comment: @Trapss 1. simplemente deja de mantener sincronizados los buffers. 2. No es lo mismo, al usar los dos puntos se llama al constructor de la variable a inicializar, mientras que si lo haces dentro de las llaves primero se invocará al constructor por defecto y luego al operador de asignación. 3. No es mi intención hacerte todo el ejercicio, hay cosas que debes probar por tu cuenta. 4. Cuando te interese vaciar un buffer **de salida**

Comment: Gracias si es verdad que no es la intención que hagas todo no busco eso busco aprender y expandir mis conocimientos ahora mismo juego con el código para aprender espero no tener mas dudas si todo me funciona te volveré a escribir para darte las gracias. ahora el nullptr no me funciona me dice que no se ha declarado en este caso es mejor usar "NULL"?

Comment: @Trapss es una característica de c++11... estándar que vio la luz en 2011. Eso es que usas un compilador que tiene mínimo 10 años de antigüedad... una barbaridad en este mundo. Es más seguro que `NULL` porque solo se puede usar con punteros